# Positioning this element to the center of the page - CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I've been battling this for quite some time and I'm not having much luck, it always gets repositioned all over the place!

I essentially want my control to center this component in the middle of the page.  I also want to rotate flip it(3d) around it's center axis(Y or X, doesn't matter) but I'm having no luck with the first step which is just getting it to the center.

```
<div className="note-container">
                <div className="note"
                    style={Object.assign({}, note.position) }>
                    <p>{note.text}</p>
                    <span>
                        <button onClick={() => onExpand(note.id) }
                            className="btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-resize-full"/>
                        <button onClick={() => onEdit(note.id) }
                            className="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"/>
                        <button onClick={onRemove}
                            className="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash"/>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The function I'm calling to reposition it to the center is  `function onExpand(noteId){...}`

Here is the CSS for `.note-container` and `.note`

```
div.note-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 5%;
    left: 90%;
}

div.note {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 2px 0;
    position: relative;
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

div.note:active {
    cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
}

div.note p {
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: "Shadows Into Light", Arial;
}

div.note div.back p {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: "Shadows Into Light", Arial;
}

div.note:hover> span {
    opacity: 1;
}

div.note> span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .25s linear;
}

div.note button {
    margin: 2px;
}

div.note> textarea {
    height: 75%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
```

And here is the onExpand function

```
    onExpand(noteId) {

    //This needs a lot of work....
    event.preventDefault();

    let flippedNote = this.props.notes
        .filter(note => note.id === noteId)[0];
    flippedNote.position.transition = "1.0s";
    flippedNote.position.transformStyle = "preserve-3d";
    flippedNote.position.backgroundColor = "#3498db";
    flippedNote.position.color = "white";
    flippedNote.position.width = "300px";
    flippedNote.position.height = "300px";

    flippedNote.position.position = "absolute";
    flippedNote.position.right = `50% -${flippedNote.position.width / 2}px`;
    flippedNote.position.top = `50% -${flippedNote.position.height / 2}px`;
    // flippedNote.position.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(180deg)";

    this.setState({/*Stuff later... */});
}
```

Also when I render the note on the page I assign it a random location on the page based on this logic(this is what is initially passed into the style attribute in the div.note element:

```
position: {
                    right: randomBetween(0, window.innerWidth - 150) + "px",
                    top: randomBetween(0, window.innerHeight - 150) + "px",
                    transform: "rotate(" + randomBetween(-15, 15) + "deg)"
                }
```

Here is what the html on the page looks like(note I am also dragging the sticky note across the page using transform: translate(...).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the final solution after working on it this weekend:

```
onExpand(noteId, currentNotePosition) {

        event.preventDefault();
        let note = this.props.notes
            .filter(specificNote => specificNote.id === noteId)[0];

        const centerOfWindow = {
            left: window.innerWidth / 2,
            top: window.innerHeight / 2
        };

        if (!note.centered) {
            note.position.transition = "all 1s";
            note.position.transformStyle = "preserve-3d";
            note.position.backgroundColor = "#3498db";
            note.position.color = "white";
            note.position.width = "300px";
            note.position.height = "300px";
            note.position.zIndex = "100";
            note.position.position = "relative";
            const offset = {
                x: 150,
                y: 150
            };
            const translatedCoordinates = this.getCoordinateTarget(centerOfWindow, offset, currentNotePosition);
            note.position.transform = `translate(${translatedCoordinates.x}px, ${translatedCoordinates.y}px) rotateY(180deg)`;

            note.originalPosition = {
                left: currentNotePosition.left,
                top: currentNotePosition.top,
                width: currentNotePosition.width,
                movement: translatedCoordinates
            };

            note.centered = true;
        } else {
            note.position.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            note.position.color = "black";
            note.position.width = "150px";
            note.position.height = "150px";
            note.position.transform = "";
            note.centered = false;
        }

        this.props.stickyNoteActions.repositionedNoteSuccess(Object.assign({}, note));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
div.note 
 {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 2px auto;
 }
```

Comment: not having any luck with this, I have a feeling my other sstyles are overriding all of this

Answer (score 1):

To control the position, you can set `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;` on your `div.note`.

Alternatively, this can be done by manipulating margins, but it's not really a good way.

You can test your code manually by opening the page in browser and manipulating CSS values through Chrome's developer tools.

Comment: I've tried both but I feel like I've hit a wall based on how I've been modifying the translation and the other styles.  What do you think based on the image above?